# TFX / Tensorflow Data Validation (TFDV) does not work on data drift

Tags: python, pandas, validation, data-analysis, tfx

I'm not sure what the problem is with the code below. I read the documentations and all of them point to an approach similar to this one.

Here is a simple example that doesn't work. My expectation was a notice for the feature `x1` since the distribution is very different between two datasets.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv

NUM_VALS_TRAIN = 10000

# -------- Today --------

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': np.random.normal(4, 3, NUM_VALS_TRAIN),
    'x2': np.random.normal(-3, 4, NUM_VALS_TRAIN)})

stats_train_today = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_dataframe(df)

# -------- Yesterday --------

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': np.random.normal(400, 300, NUM_VALS_TRAIN),
    'x2': np.random.normal(-3, 4, NUM_VALS_TRAIN)})

stats_train_yesterday = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_dataframe(df)

# -------- Validate --------

schema = tfdv.infer_schema(stats_train_yesterday)

tfdv.get_feature(schema, 'x1').drift_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold = 0.01

anomalies = tfdv.validate_statistics(statistics=stats_train_today,
                                     schema=schema,
                                     previous_statistics=stats_train_yesterday)

tfdv.display_anomalies(anomalies)
```

The result is always `No anomalies found.`

What is wrong with this code?

(Using tfx==0.24.1)

Comment: Try using `drift_comparator.jensen_shannon_divergence.threshold` instead of `drift_comparator.infinity_norm.threshold`.

Comment: `jensen_shannon_divergence` did work! Thank you so much @KeyurPotdar!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found this at https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/blob/master/RELEASE.md

"Add support for detecting drift and distribution skew in numeric features"

Turns out it is not implemented yet.

Comment: please check the below links for implementation of js diveregence - https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/get_started
https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/event-triggered-detection-data-drift-ml-workflows

also, below snippet is used for the same,
tfdv.get_feature(schema1, 'duration').drift_comparator.jensen_shannon_divergence.threshold = 0.01

Answer (score 0):

Jenson Shannon is for numerical features, and infinity norm is for categorical. It seems you have used infinity norm for numerical features, which will obviously not work. Check [Drift Detection](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/tfdv#tensorflow_data_validation) which says:

> "Drift detection is supported between consecutive spans of data (i.e.,
> between span N and span N+1), such as between different days of
> training data. We express drift in terms of L-infinity distance for
> categorical features and approximate Jensen-Shannon divergence for
> numeric features. You can set the threshold distance so that you
> receive warnings when the drift is higher than is acceptable. Setting
> the correct distance is typically an iterative process requiring
> domain knowledge and experimentation."